# Mapping my user function in several columns with purrr

Tags: r, function, dictionary, purrr

I´m trying to use `map` function to apply it in several columns in my dataframe. My function has two parameters; data and a column, and works fine, but I´d like to apply it a several columns in the same time. For example, that's how it works with the variable BAD (numerical)

```
> frec_procedure<-function(data,colu){
+ 
+   data%>% count({{colu}},name = "Frecuency") %>% 
+     mutate(Percent =formattable::percent(Frecuency / sum(Frecuency)),
+            Cumulative_Freq=cumsum(Frecuency),
+            Cumulative_Perc=cumsum(Percent))
+ }
> 
> d1 %>% frec_procedure(BAD)
# A tibble: 2 x 5
    BAD Frecuency Percent    Cumulative_Freq Cumulative_Perc
  <dbl>     <int> <formttbl>           <int> <formttbl>     
1     0      4771 80.05%                4771 80.05%         
2     1      1189 19.95%                5960 100.00%
```

or with variable JOB(character)

```
d1 %>% frec_procedure(JOB)
# A tibble: 7 x 5
  JOB     Frecuency Percent    Cumulative_Freq Cumulative_Perc
  <chr>       <int> <formttbl>           <int> <formttbl>     
1 Mgr           767 12.87%                 767 12.87%         
2 Office        948 15.91%                1715 28.78%         
3 Other        2388 40.07%                4103 68.84%         
4 ProfExe      1276 21.41%                5379 90.25%         
5 Sales         109 1.83%                 5488 92.08%         
6 Self          193 3.24%                 5681 95.32%         
7 NA            279 4.68%                 5960 100.00%
```

So, the trouble is when I try to apply my function in others variables at the same time using `map` function (`purr` package). I´m using this to map the function, but the results are only show the total number of cases of d1 without considering the frec_procedure per variable

```
> try_map <- tibble(vars = c("BAD", "JOB", "REASON")) %>% 
+   mutate(metrics = vars %>% map(~frec_procedure(d1)))
> try_map$metrics
[[1]]
# A tibble: 1 x 4
  Frecuency Percent    Cumulative_Freq Cumulative_Perc
      <int> <formttbl>           <int> <formttbl>     
1      5960 100.00%               5960 100.00%        

[[2]]
# A tibble: 1 x 4
  Frecuency Percent    Cumulative_Freq Cumulative_Perc
      <int> <formttbl>           <int> <formttbl>     
1      5960 100.00%               5960 100.00%        

[[3]]
# A tibble: 1 x 4
  Frecuency Percent    Cumulative_Freq Cumulative_Perc
      <int> <formttbl>           <int> <formttbl>     
1      5960 100.00%               5960 100.00%
```

I would appreciate any advice or help possible to achieve the outcome. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `{{}}` works with unquoted arguments.  In order to pass quoted, we may have to convert to `sym`bol and evaluate (`!!`)  - `ensym` does that

```
frec_procedure<-function(data,colu){

   data%>% count(!! rlang::ensym(colu),name = "Frecuency") %>% 
     mutate(Percent =formattable::percent(Frecuency / sum(Frecuency)),
            Cumulative_Freq=cumsum(Frecuency),
            Cumulative_Perc=cumsum(Percent))
 }
```

-testing

```
> map(c("cyl", "vs"), ~ frec_procedure(mtcars, !! .x))
[[1]]
  cyl Frecuency Percent Cumulative_Freq Cumulative_Perc
1   4        11  34.38%              11          34.38%
2   6         7  21.88%              18          56.25%
3   8        14  43.75%              32         100.00%

[[2]]
  vs Frecuency Percent Cumulative_Freq Cumulative_Perc
1  0        18  56.25%              18          56.25%
2  1        14  43.75%              32         100.00%

> frec_procedure(mtcars, cyl)
  cyl Frecuency Percent Cumulative_Freq Cumulative_Perc
1   4        11  34.38%              11          34.38%
2   6         7  21.88%              18          56.25%
3   8        14  43.75%              32         100.00%
```

Comment: @TarJae thanks for notifying.  With `mtcars`, it is working fine after the change i.e. `frec_procedure(mtcars, mpg)`

Comment: Yes indeed, but in this case also the OPs original function works.

Comment: @TarJae maybe you didn't escape.  Updated the post

Comment: @akrun thanks for your time, but with `!! rlang::ensym()`  the same result is maintained (the same like try_map) I think the problem is in try_map, since this is where I can't get frec_procedure to perform the analysis of the variables.

Comment: @boris_traveler I showed a reproducible example with `mtcars` data which gives the same result in a loop and when you enter outside a loop

Comment: @boris_traveler sorry, not clear about your comment.  Your comment in the question was `total number of cases of d1 without considering the frec_procedure per variable`.  Here, with `mtcars`, it does consider that

Comment: @akrun. You are right with escaping your code works. @boris_traveler notice this `map(c("cyl", "vs"), ~ frec_procedure(mtcars, !! .x))` to apply akrun's version of the function.